# SQL ORDER BY total within GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I heed some help constructing a SQL statment.  Currently I have the following:

```
SELECT a, b, count(1)
 FROM table
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY a asc, count(1) DESC
```

Each row displays the sum of all the unique B's within each grouping a and orders by A alphabetically and then by highest occurrence of B to the lowest.  What I would actually like is to be able to sort by the total within each grouping of A (consider every row as a subtotal).

Comment: Can you please provide an example of data output. e.g. currently you have, say, "USA, California, 15", "USA, Washington, 10"; "Australia, Victoria, 3". How do you want to re-arrange that data?

Comment: "What I would actually like is to be able to sort by the total within each grouping of A (consider every row as a subtotal)."    
The total of b?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. Could you clarify and maybe add a small example table, current results, and the results you want to get?

Comment: @PP
In the exact order you wrote them in.

Comment: cube or rollup modifiers maybe? `group by rollup (a, b)`, see <http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html>

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  a, b, COUNT(*) AS bcnt,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.a = mo.a
        ) AS acnt
FROM    mytable mo
GROUP BY
        a, b
ORDER BY
        acnt DESC, bcnt DESC
```