# GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL ORDER BY total within GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237918/sql-order-by-total-within-group-by)

```
SELECT *
FROM users_pm_in
WHERE uID = '1'
GROUP BY dialog_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Wont work properly. What i want to do is group in to dialog_id.. Then all with the dialog_id sort them by date, and then sort them by date for all..

So:

```
id | uID | bID | msg     | dialog_id | date
--------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1   | 2   | Hello   | 1         | 1289158631
 2 | 2   | 1   | Hi?     | 1         | 1289158691
 3 | 1   | 2   | Wazzaa? | 1         | 1289158931
```

The two entry´s of the dialog_id gets 1 (With GROUP BY). OK. And then it should order by the one of the two entrys(inside the group) that have the newest date(order by date desc). Which this case is the one with date 1289158931.

How can this be done?

UPDATE:

What i want to come out:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $row["msg"] // it should echo "Wazzaa?"
    echo $row["id"] // it should give me id 3
}
```

It give me the last for each dialog_id, thats why i want it grouped in.

Comment: your date is 1289158931?

Comment: Please provide your expected output, based on the sample data.

Comment: If I understand correctly he wants to sort his "groups" by dates too. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT a.id, 
         a.msg
    FROM USERS_PM a
   WHERE a.dialog_id = 1
     AND 1 IN (a.uid, a.bid)
ORDER BY a.date DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

...or:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.msg
  FROM USERS_PM a
  JOIN (SELECT t.dialog_id,
               MAX(t.date) AS max_date
          FROM USERS_PM t
      GROUP BY t.dialog_id) b ON b.dialog_id = a.dialog_id
                             AND b.max_date = a.date
 WHERE a.dialog_id = 1
   AND 1 IN (a.uid, a.bid)
```

Comment: + `ORDER BY a.date DESC` at the very end.

Comment: why WHERE dialog_id = ? I shouldnt specify a dialog_id?

Comment: @Johnson: If you leave out the WHERE clause, you'll get the latest post for each dialog_id value.

Comment: @Omg Ponies I removed the WHERE clause, and I am not getting returned any rows

Comment: @Johnson: That's impossible, based on the sample provided.  Are there details you've left out, or did you make a mistake when using the query I provided?  I added an alternative query, using LIMIT.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, or wait it's because you havnt selected stuff that I need.. let me just test once again

Comment: @Johnson: The columns match the sample data, and what you list for expected output.

Comment: @OMG Ponies starts to work now, although where should i have my  WHERE uID = '$USER' like I have in my first query?

Comment: Something is not right at all. When there's coming a new row (if a user1 responds to user2, and has same dialog_id), the message he responded to goes away in the income list, and appears in user2. and when user2 responds, it disappears from user2´s incomelist and appears in user1...

Comment: fixed , added GROUP BY t.dialog, t.uID