# MySQL GROUP BY / ORDER BY issue with flat messages table / threads

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, messaging

Ok, I'm trying to base something similar off of this, but not quite getting it nailed: [GROUP BY and ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119576/group-by-and-order-by/6471137)

Basically, wanting a query to find the latest messages in each 'thread' between the current logged-in user and any other users, but via a flat (non-'threaded') table of messages:

```
messages {
  id,
  from_uid,
  to_uid,
  message_text,
  time_added
}
```

Assuming the current user's uid is '1', and the latest message in each 'thread' could either be *from* that user, or *to* that user (the other party always denoted by thread_recipient):

```
SELECT a.*,thread_recipient
  FROM messages a
  JOIN (SELECT IF(from_uid = '1',to_uid,from_uid) AS thread_recipient,
               MAX(time_added) AS recency
          FROM messages 
         WHERE (from_uid = '1' OR to_uid = '1')
      GROUP BY thread_recipient) b ON thread_recipient = (IF(a.from_uid = '1',a.to_uid,a.from_uid))
                             AND b.recency = a.time_added
 ORDER BY a.time_added DESC
```

But I fear this ain't gonna work right, and maybe messages sent at the same time might end up being returned for the wrong user?

Is my WHERE condition misplaced?

Any wisdom much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea: take the UNION of the following two queries, then get
the maximum dates from the result.

```
SELECT id,to_uid AS other_party,time_added FROM messages WHERE from_uid = '1'

SELECT id,from_uid AS other_party,time_added FROM messages WHERE to_uid = '1'
```

When you do the following:

```
SELECT MAX(time_added),other_party
FROM (SELECT id,to_uid AS other_party,time_added FROM messages WHERE from_uid = '1'
      UNION
      SELECT id,from_uid AS other_party,time_added FROM messages WHERE to_uid = '1'
     ) MyMessages
GROUP BY other_party
```

You will get the most recent time associated with a message sent to
each person that user '1' is corresponding with. Then you can join the
results of that to the original messages table to get what you want:

```
SELECT Messages.*
FROM (SELECT MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime,other_party
      FROM (SELECT id,to_uid AS other_party,time_added FROM messages WHERE from_uid = '1'
            UNION
            SELECT id,from_uid AS other_party,time_added FROM messages WHERE to_uid = '1'
           ) MyMessages
      GROUP BY other_party
     )
     JOIN Messages
     ON (Messages.time_added = MyMessages.MaxTime AND
          (Messages.to_uid = MyMessages.other_party AND Messages.from_uid = '1' OR
           Messages.from_uid = MyMessages.other_party AND Messages.to_uid = '1')
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - I think it gives you what you are looking for more simply and efficiently.

```
SELECT latest_time = MAX(a.time_added, b.time_added)
FROM messages a, messages b

LEFT JOIN messages a1
    ON a1.from_uid = a.from_id

-- find the case where the following doesn't exist
-- so you know there is nothing after b1
LEFT JOIN messages a2
    ON a2.from_uid = a.from_id
    AND a2.time_added > a1.time_added

LEFT JOIN messages b1
    ON b1.to_uid = b.to_id

LEFT JOIN messages b2
    ON b2.to_uid = b.to_id
    AND b2.time_added > b1.time_added

WHERE a.from_id = '1'
    AND b.to_id = '1'
    AND c1.id IS NULL
    AND c2.id IS NULL

ORDER BY a.time_added DESC
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, there is no `thread_recipient` column in the `messages` table, which is the essence of the problem. Messages have from and to, but when doing this query we are looking from the standpoint of user `'1'` and want to call "the other guy" by `thread_recipient`.

Comment: I think that mostly works. It definitely works as long as at least one message has been sent both to and from user '1' in the thread. But I think maybe I've spent too long on this question already; the questioner should be able to use one of our two answers to make something happen!    +1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after comments - if id is autoincrement use it instead of message time. But you have propoer condition to ensure that messages will not be delivered to wrong persons.

Comment: He wants the most recent message, and he wants the most recent message sent to/from each person he is corresponding with.

Comment: ... you still aren't returning one message per correspondent, which is the point of the question.