# SQL group & sort by two columns

Tags: php, sql, database, group-by, sql-order-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL ORDER BY total within GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237918/sql-order-by-total-within-group-by)

**UPDATE: I've found my solution, which I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11264711/1207056). Thanks to everyone for your help!**

---

I'm developing a Facebook application which requires a leaderboard. Scores and time taken to complete the game are recorded and these are organised by score first, then in the case of two identical scores, the time is used. If a user has played multiple times, their best score is used.

The lower the score, the better the performance in the game.

My table structure is:

```
id
facebook_id - (Unique Identifier for the user)
name
email
score
time - (time to complete game in seconds)
timestamp - (unix timestamp of entry)
date - (readable format of timestamp)
ip
```

The query I thought would work is:

```
SELECT *
FROM entries
ORDER BY score ASC, time ASC
GROUP BY facebook_id
```

The problem I'm having is in some cases it's pulling in the user's first score in the database, not their highest score. I think this is down to the GROUP BY statement. I would have thought the ORDER BY statement would have fixed this, but apparently not.

For example:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  ID  |       NAME       |  SCORE  |  TIME  |  TIMESTAMP  |  DATE  |  IP  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |  Joe Bloggs      |  65     |   300  | 1234567890  |  XXX   |  XXX |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |  Jane Doe        |  72     |   280  | 1234567890  |  XXX   |  XXX |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3   |  Joe Bloggs      |  55     |   285  | 1234567890  |  XXX   |  XXX |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  4   |  Jane Doe        |  78     |   320  | 1234567890  |  XXX   |  XXX |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I use the query above, I get the following result:

```
 1. Joe Bloggs - 65 - 300 - (Joes First Entry, not his best entry) 
 2. Jane Doe - 72 - 280
```

I would have expected...

```
 1. Joe Bloggs - 55 - 285 - (Joe's best entry)
 2. Jane Doe - 72 - 280
```

It's like the Group By is ignoring the Order - and just overwriting the values.

Using MIN(score) with the group by selects the lowest score, which is correct - however it merges the time from the users first record in the database, so often returns incorrectly.

So, how can I select a user's highest score and the associated time, name, etc and order the results by score, then time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `WHERE` condition is sorely missing. When using `GROUP BY`, the engine has the right to choose absolutely any column from the grouped items, even from different row for every column.

Comment: `ORDER BY` goes _after_ the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: use a multicolumn `UNIQUE` index.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: @RedFilter - Updated the question to include some sample data.

T-Shirt Dude - I'm not sure what a Unique index would do in this case.

Teran - Unfortunately when I try this, the Group By statement merges the first time in the database into the returned row - so it's not returning the correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be this:

```
SELECT entries.facebook_id, MIN(entries.score) AS score, MIN(entries.time) AS time
FROM entries
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT facebook_id, MIN(score) AS score
        FROM entries
        GROUP BY facebook_id) highscores
    ON highscores.facebook_id = entries.facebook_id
    AND entries.score = highscores.score
GROUP BY entries.facebook_id
ORDER BY MIN(entries.score) ASC, MIN(entries.time) ASC
```

If you need more information from the entries table, you can then use this as a subquery, and join again on the information presented (facebook_id, score, time) to get one row per user.

You need to aggregate twice, is the crux of this; once to find the minimum score for the user, and again to find the minimum time for that user and score. You could reverse the order of the aggregation, but I would expect that this will filter most quickly and thus be most efficient.

You might also want to check which is faster, aggregating the second time: using the minimum score or grouping using the score as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your query does not actually make sense, because the order by should be after the group by.  What SQL engine are you using?  Most would give an error.

I think what you want is more like:

```
select e.facebookid, minscore, min(e.time) as mintime -- or do you want maxtime?
from entries e join
     (select e.facebookid, min(score) as minscore
      from entries e
      group by facebookid
     ) esum
     on e.facebookid = esum.facebookid and
        e.score = e.minscore
group by e.facebookid, minscore
```

You can also do this with window functions, but that depends on your database.

Comment: Sorry, my statement above was incorrect - Order By is after the group by. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to min the score

```
    SELECT
      facebook_id,
      name,
      email,
      min(score) as high_score
    FROM
      entries
    GROUP BY
      facebook_id,
      name,
      email
   ORDER BY
     min(score) ASC
```

Comment: Hi @Phil - I've tried this and a few variations today. Unfortunately it returns each entry a user has made - it doesn't select the single highest score for each user.

Comment: remove ID and time from the group by and select.  Sorry about that initial answer I will edit

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help. @Penguat had the closest answer.. Here was my final Query for anyone who might have the same issue...

```
SELECT f.facebook_id, f.name, f.score, f.time FROM
    (SELECT facebook_id, name, min(score)
    AS highscore FROM golf_entries
    WHERE time > 0
    GROUP BY facebook_id)
AS x
INNER JOIN golf_entries as f
ON f.facebook_id = x.facebook_id
AND f.score = x.highscore
ORDER BY score ASC, time ASC
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want their best time, you want to use the MIN() function - you said that the lower the score, the better they did.

```
SELECT facebook_id, MIN(score), time, name, ... 
FROM entries 
GROUP BY facebook_id, time, name, ...
ORDER BY score, time
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not quite what I want though - this outputs all scores by all entrants in order. I only want each user's highest score and the time associated with it.

I've been fighting with it all day.. I'm sure I'm missing something stupidly simple.

Comment: What about the case where a user has two identical scores, but with different times - is a higher or lower time better?